# Is it possible to have different dock location per monitor?

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, dock

I have 2 monitors -- A and B.

I want the **dock** at the **bottom on monitor A**, while I want it on the **top on monitor B**

```
A |    |   B |dock|
  |    |     |----|
  |    |     |    |
  |----|     |    |
  |dock|     |    |
```

Is this possible to achieve on ubuntu?

Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: @guiverc thanks for your kind comment, I modified my question so that it can be on-topic here.

Comment: Different DEs allow different things... FYI:  I'm using 5 monitors; have a panel on the bottom of my primary monitor, & dock on the left side.. On the monitor above my primary I have panel at the top, on monitor to right of my primary I have a panel on bottom, on monitors (2) to left of my upper monitor I have another dock on far left monitor on left side (ie. multiple panels & multiple docks where I find them useful).  My layout is strange; but this box only uses 5 of the 8 monitors in front of me thus my *strange* setup.